# Dulwich: How to automatically stage modified files

Tags: python, git, dulwich

In git command line, we can use `git commit -a`.

How can I do that using dulwich?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When considering the various tests for a commit, like those in [`test_repository.py`](https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/blob/master/dulwich/tests/test_repository.py#L446-L461), it doesn't seem to be possible in one line:

```
    r.stage(['a'])
    commit_sha = r.do_commit('modified a',
                             committer='Test Committer <test@nodomain.com>',
                             author='Test Author <test@nodomain.com>',
                             commit_timestamp=12395, commit_timezone=0,
                             author_timestamp=12395, author_timezone=0)
```

You need to find modified or deleted files first, and stage them, before calling the commit.

The other alternative would be to use [git-python](http://gitorious.org/projects/git-python), which is a wrapper to git, but it doesn't offer either that feature out of the box.

Comment: Note that apart from the commit message the other arguments to r.do_commit() are optional.